# Use a balanced training set in weka

Tags: machine-learning, weka

Is there a way to make weka use a balanced training set, where it only takes an equal number of instances for each class?

Comment: Did you try use resampling filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Classify panel choose metalearner "FilteredClassifier", and make its filter parameter "weka.filter.supervised.instance.ClassBalancer". Then select which classifier to use, i.e. J48, AdaBoost, etc.